# Javascript Multiple Class Inheritence (Book Store as an example with these three classes: Member, Book, Transaction)

Tags: javascript

I have 2 classes.

```
function Book(title, price){
  this.title = title;
  this.price = price; }

function Member(name, level){
  this.name = name;
  this.level = level; } // Level or Subscription or something like that

Member.prototype.getDiscount = function(level){
  if(this.level.toUpperCase() === 'GOLD') return 0.5;
  elseif(this.level.toUpperCase() === 'SILVER') return 0.2;
  else return 0; }

// a Silver Member has 20% discount (all book)
// a Gold Member has 50% discount (all book)

b1 = new Book('book A', 500);
b2 = new Book('book B', 200);
b3 = new Book('book C', 400);

m1 = new Member('Alex', 'Gold');
m2 = new Member('Bruce', 'Silver');
m3 = new Member('Christine', 'Gold');
```

I want a new `Transaction` class:

```
t1 = new Transaction(m1, [b2, 3]);                         // Alex bought 3 'book B' for 300.
t2 = new Transaction(m1, [[b1, 2], [b3, 4], [b2, 1]]);     // Alex bought 2 'book A' for 500,
                                                           //             4 'book C' for 800
                                                           //         and 1 'book B' for 100.
```

`Transaction` has two constructor. The first constructor is who bought the book. The second constructor is a 1D array (one book title only) or 2D array (more than 1 different books title).
The result of calling `m1.bag`: (bunch of `console log`s)

```
Member Name  : Alex
Member Level : Gold
Transaction History :
 #1
  x3 'book B' : 600
  Total       : 300
 #2
  x2 'book A' : 1000
  x4 'book C' : 1600
  x1 'book B' : 200
  Total       : 1400
 #Total       : 1700
```

when `m2.bag` is called:

```
Member Name : Bruce
Member Level: Silver
Transaction History :
```

`m2` and `m3`'s `Transaction` ain't declared yet.

Summary:
 - How to make a relation between `Book` and `Member` into `Transaction`
 - How to make a dynamic constructor which can be either 1D or 2D.
Thank You.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried to accomplish the `Transaction` class! Where should it put data collected by the constructor, and what should it do besides that?

Comment: I tried with mixin, prototype, etc but failed. `Transaction` is kind of 'bridge' that connects `Book` and `Member`. In `Transaction` I wanted to calculate each member's purchase with their own discount. The final outcome that I wanted is `m1.bag` which I expect to be an additional prototype in Member (just like `getDiscount()` function but with 'spices' from `Transaction`. Sorry if it is hard to understand. I am kind of beginner.